Optimizing Redis and Files cache layer in PHP
I'm working on a project that has a dual layer cache fallback, so instead of getting the data directly from a MySQL database, it tries to do the following instead:

if CACHE_REDIS is true, it tries to get the data from the Redis server (which was set previously with cache_write()).
if CACHE_FILES is true, and if no data was found on Redis, it tries to get the data from a json file (which was also written previously with cache_write()).
if $data is still null, it tries to get the data directly from the MySQL database.

The Redis key and Cache filename, is defined in the $key variable, using the original sql query, and optionally any WHERE variables ($querystring).
So for example, if I want to get the names from a specific category, I would run this code:
$sql = 'SELECT cat, name FROM stats WHERE cat = :cat';

# try to get data from cache
if(!$data = cache_check($sql, $cat)) {
    # get data from db
    $stmt = cnn()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':cat', $cat, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    if($data = $stmt->fetchAll()) {
        # write data to cache
        cache_write($sql, $cat, $data);
    }
}

These are the functions that handle both the Redis and Files reading and writing actions:
# debugger
define('CACHE_REDIS', true);
define('CACHE_FILES', true);
define('DIR_CACHE', '/some/path/cache/');

# create redis object
function cache_connection() {
    static $cache;
    if(CACHE_REDIS) {
        if(!isset($cache)) {
            $cache = new Redis();
            $cache->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
        }
        return $cache;
    }

    # default
    return false;
}

# cache check
function cache_check($sql, $querystring=false, $seconds_to_live=3600) {
    # key
    $key = md5($sql.'@@'.$querystring);

    if(CACHE_REDIS) {
        # redis object
        $redis = cache_connection();

        # key data
        if($redis->exists($key)) {
            # json
            return json_decode($redis->get($key), true);
        }
    }

    if(CACHE_FILES) {
        # try to get from local file
        $file_path = DIR_CACHE.$key.'.cache';
        $file_modified = null;

        # check for file aliveness
        if(file_exists($file_path)) {
            $file_modified = filemtime($file_path);
            if(time() - $file_modified < $seconds_to_live) {
                # get data from cache
                $fp = fopen($file_path, 'r'); // read-only
                $json = fread($fp, filesize($file_path));
                fclose($fp);
                $data = json_decode($json, true);

                # json
                return $data;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

# write cache
function cache_write($sql, $querystring=false, $data, $seconds_to_live=3600) {
    # key
    $key = md5($sql.'@@'.$querystring);
    
    if(CACHE_REDIS) {
        # redis object
        $redis = cache_connection();

        # save to redis
        $redis->set($key, json_encode($data));
        $redis->expire($key, $seconds_to_live); 
    }

    if(CACHE_FILES) {
        # save to local file
        $file_path = DIR_CACHE.$key.'.cache';

        # open cache file
        $fp = fopen($file_path, 'w'); // write truncate
        if(flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
            ftruncate($fp, 0); // truncate file
            fwrite($fp, json_encode($data));
            fflush($fp); // flush output before releasing the lock
            flock($fp, LOCK_UN); // release the lock
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
}

I'm having second thoughts about the cache_connection() function, which tries to reuse the same Redis object to avoid multiple connections by the same client (a single page can  make up to 10 different requests to other tables). Is this a correct approach? It has been done this way because in some servers where the app is going to be installed, there is no Redis availability, so it's easier to just turn it off with the constant variable CACHE_REDIS.
I would really appreciate your view on this issue, and if possible, to optimize this.

Sorry, but "thoughts" cannot be optimized. And there is no other problem definition in your question

"Is this a correct approach?" I don't know that "correct" is the best word to use here, but that's the way I would do it, as you certainly don't want each separate Redis query to incur its own separate connection overhead.

Note you don't need if(CACHE_REDIS) { in the cache_connection() function, as that never gets called when CACHE_REDIS is false. I'd also question the usefulness of this json file caching, I'd wager it's slower than hitting the database for most queries.

Worth mentioning that mysql caches queries internally, and the OS caches the underlying file blocks for mysql. Calling out to the FS for naive, bespoke file caching is going to be a net negative for all but the biggest queries, or those run against data that is infrequently accessed.

You should do some actual performance benchmarks rather than just plowing ahead with the mindset of "more cache is more better".
